# How to automatically hide a fixed dimension from bottom of image for varying image sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am designing a new blog gallery for a client using elementor & wordpress. The client's images for each respective blog contains a footer watermark for each image. The client wishes to hide the footer watermark in the gallery view. When the user interacts with the images (on-click) the lightbox will be activated and then the full image will be displayed including the previously hidden footer. The height of the images all vary in dimension (see below), but the saving grace is that the footer and width remain the same dimensions throughout (see below).

As I have created the single-post as a template in elementor the gallery can be displayed via

1. Post Content (elementor) which pulls through exactly from WP
2. Image Gallery Widget (elementor) which can be dynamically linked to the post attachments.

I have targeted both elements mentioned above and used the following css:

```
    {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 915px, 609px, 0);
    }
```

This does create the desired effect for certain images only BUT, the alignment is all out.
If I remove the POSITION from the css and activate POSITION within the elementor widget, the alignment is rectified HOWEVER anything that was below it ie another section is now displayed directly behind or on-top of it, depending on z-index.

How can one achieve to hide the footer watermark automatically for all images in the gallery that have varying dimensions?

Varying image dimensions:

```
* footer = 80px
* w x h
    * 915x689px
    * 915x784px
    * 915x1453px
```

Comment: Hello.
So I managed to fix it.
Via CSS I targeted the element class and image.
I set the width to 100% and height to auto.
And then I set the margin-bottom to negative the pixel value I required.